# Android XML error:junk after document element/Root element must be well formed

Tags: java, android, xml

I have absolutely no Idea what im doing wrong I get two errors- junk after document element and markup after root must be well formed, any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<EditText  android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"  />
</EditText>
<button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two errors that I see.

1. `LinearLayout` should not have a `/` at the end of the top declaration.  That is probably causing your XML errors.
2. `button` should be capitalized.